# diff and merge of XML

Tags: xml, devtools

Can anyone recommend a good XML diff and merge tool?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871076).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_diff_and_merge.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Project: Merge](http://www.projectmerge.com) - Not free, but not expensive either.