# XSLT to sort nodes by name?

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I'm unsure how the `xsl:sort` directive works. I need to sort elements by their tag name (for diffing), and I can't seem to come up with how to make this work. My first though was to modify the identity transform and just modify it to include a sort statement, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
              <!-- xsl:sort ? -->
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please, provide a small source XML document and also the expected result from the transformation.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that also sorts attributes and for a warning.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
    <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
    <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t b="x" c="y" a="t">
  <c/>
  <b/>
  <a/>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted sorted output**:

```
<t a="t" b="x" c="y">
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
</t>
```

**Do note**:

1. **Not only the elements but also the attributes are sorted** (the latter is implementation dependent, but works OK with MSXML).
2. **Using sorted XML for diffs is unreliable**, because converting an XML document to a sorted representation isn't 1:1 mapping.

Comment: If the XML structure is purely accessed via DOM, why wouldn't the sorted documents be able to be diffed?

Comment: @Stefan-Kendall: Because an element may have the same number of identically named children (in the two documents) but in very different order in each of the documents. Both documents will be transformed to produce identical lists of children for this element and the diff operation (or just personal observation) will not find any difference.

Comment: Order isn't guaranteed in the documents I'm parsing anyway, and anything at the same level is equivalent, so I guess this should work.

Comment: @Stefan-Kendall: Two XML documents *are* different even if the only difference is in the order of elements.

Comment: ...not when my application defines the order as irrelevant. :P

Comment: I'd also like to note as part of the answer that the splitting of the `apply-template` is necessary to keep the `sort` descriptor from handling nodes and attributes in the same serialized order. As soon as the first node after an attribute is hit, no further attributes can be processed. By splitting the sort directive, we avoid this issue and get the sorting desired.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev *Two XML documents are different even if the only difference is in the order of elements.* Could you give some reference?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost, Yes: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-deep-equal

Comment: This is an extremely useful XSLT if you want "sanitise" XML before running a compare. Yes, order of elements is semantically significant, but in practice we often see tooling ignore the order and even generate XML with an "arbitrary" order (e.g. different each time). This creates XML-files that, DOM-wise may be identical, but text-wise are very different (including other pains like random indentation, different node closing styles, etc)

Comment: @MartinDevillers, Correct observation. In case an XML document is a serialization of a PL object, then the order of elements that represent properties, is not important. However, if the XML document is a representation of a document, then the order of its elements (such as representing chapters and sub-sections) is of critical importance.