# Sort XML elements by name, and further sort elements by text

Tags: xslt

I'd like to know how I can sort XML based on first element name, and than by text of few of those elements.
in basic terms if I have elements 'd, e, c, a, b' elements at same level, I'd like them to be ordered as 'a, b, c, d, e'.
And the other requirement is to sort the groups of a/b/c/d/e by text within 'b, c, d' elements.  So if one set of b,c,d contains 'b1, c1, d1', and the other contains 'b2, c2, d2', than the set with '1' should come out first (alphabetically, I do not need numeric order). (in sql terms: order by b, c, d)

I have XML such as.

```
<top_tag>
 <next_tag>
  <a_element>valueX</a_element>
  <b_element>valueZ</b_element>
  <d_element>
   <property>on</property>
   <header>hello</header>
   <column_name>columnC</column_name>
   <a_element>valueX</a_element>
   <b_element>valueZ</b_element>
  </d_element>
  <c_element>valueC</c_element>
  <d_element>
   <property>off</property>
   <header>hi</header>
   <column_name>columnA</column_name>
   <a_element>valueX</a_element>
   <b_element>valueZ</b_element>
  </d_element>
 </next_tag>
 <next_tag>
  <a_element>valueA</a_element>
  <b_element>valueB</b_element>
  <d_element>
   <property>on</property>
   <header>hello</header>
   <column_name>columnAAA</column_name>
   <a_element>valueA</a_element>
   <b_element>valueB</b_element>
  </d_element>
  <c_element>valueC</c_element>
  <d_element>
   <property>off</property>
   <header>hi</header>
   <column_name>columnA</column_name>
   <a_element>valueA</a_element>
   <b_element>valueB</b_element>
  </d_element>
 </next_tag>
</top_tag>
```

I'd like to get this: (sorted next_tag by 'a_element and b_element', and sorted d_element by 'a_element, b_element and column_name')

```
<top_tag>
  <next_tag>
    <a_element>valueA</a_element>
    <b_element>valueB</b_element>
    <c_element>valueC</c_element>
    <d_element>
      <a_element>valueA</a_element>
      <b_element>valueB</b_element>
      <column_name>columnA</column_name>
      <header>hi</header>
      <property>off</property>
    </d_element>
    <d_element>
      <a_element>valueA</a_element>
      <b_element>valueB</b_element>
      <column_name>columnAAA</column_name>
      <header>hello</header>
      <property>on</property>
    </d_element>
  </next_tag>
  <next_tag>
    <a_element>valueX</a_element>
    <b_element>valueZ</b_element>
    <c_element>valueC</c_element>
    <d_element>
      <a_element>valueX</a_element>
      <b_element>valueZ</b_element>
      <column_name>columnA</column_name>
      <header>hi</header>
      <property>off</property>
    </d_element>
    <d_element>
      <a_element>valueX</a_element>
      <b_element>valueZ</b_element>
      <column_name>columnC</column_name>
      <header>hello</header>
      <property>on</property>
    </d_element>
  </next_tag>
</top_tag>
```

I found how to order the elements based on alphabetical order here:
[XSLT to sort nodes by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091085/xslt-to-sort-nodes-by-name)

However if I then apply order by elements (most likely incorrectly), all the element names become scrambled (out of element-name order).

For this processing it is fine to use multiple passes with xslt to get to final result, I do not have requirement to have a single xsl file that does both (sort by element and by name)

This whole exercise is just so I could do a 'diff' (or beyond compare) and be able to understand changes in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more than one `<xsl:sort>` within an `apply-templates` or `for-each`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="top_tag">
    <top_tag>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="next_tag">
        <xsl:sort select="a_element" />
        <xsl:sort select="b_element" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </top_tag>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="next_tag">
    <next_tag>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="name()" />
        <xsl:sort select="a_element" />
        <xsl:sort select="b_element" />
        <xsl:sort select="column_name" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </next_tag>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="d_element">
    <d_element>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="name()" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </d_element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key point here is that the `select` expression of a `sort` is applied with the node being considered for sorting as the context node, thus the `next_tag` template will sort its children first by element name, and then if two elements have the same name they will be sorted by the value of their respective `a_element`, `b_element` and `column_name` children (if any), in that order.