# Sort elements of arbitrary XML document recursively

Tags: xml, xslt, groovy

I'm trying to sort and canonicalize some XML documents.  The desired end result is that:

1. **every element's children are in alphabetical order**
2. every elements attributes are in alphabetical order
3. comments are removed
4. all elements are properly spaced (i.e. "pretty print").

I have achieved all of these goals except #1.

I have been using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165464/288341) answer as my template.  Here is what I have so far:

```
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
import org.apache.xml.security.c14n.Canonicalizer

// Initialize the security library
org.apache.xml.security.Init.init()

// Create some variables

// Get arguments

// Make sure required arguments have been provided

if(!error) {
    // Create some variables
    def ext = fileInName.tokenize('.').last()
    fileOutName = fileOutName ?: "${fileInName.lastIndexOf('.').with {it != -1 ? fileInName[0..<it] : fileInName}}_CANONICALIZED_AND_SORTED.${ext}"
    def fileIn = new File(fileInName)
    def fileOut = new File(fileOutName)
    def xsltFile = new File(xsltName)
    def temp1 = new File("./temp1")
    def temp2 = new File("./temp2")
    def os
    def is

    // Sort the XML attributes, remove comments, and remove extra whitespace
    println "Canonicalizing..."
    Canonicalizer c = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_OMIT_COMMENTS)
    os = temp1.newOutputStream()
    c.setWriter(os)
    c.canonicalize(fileIn.getBytes())
    os.close()

    // Sort the XML elements
    println "Sorting..."
    def factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
    is = xsltFile.newInputStream()
    def transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(is))
    is.close()
    is = temp1.newInputStream()
    os = temp2.newOutputStream()
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(is), new StreamResult(os))
    is.close()
    os.close()

    // Write the XML output in "pretty print"
    println "Beautifying..."
    def parser = new XmlParser()
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new IndentPrinter(fileOut.newPrintWriter(), "    ", true))
    printer.print parser.parseText(temp2.getText())

    // Cleanup
    temp1.delete()
    temp2.delete()

    println "Done!"
}
```

Full script is [here](http://pastebin.com/vTrVksAA).

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <foo>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Sample Input XML:**

```
<foo b="b" a="a" c="c">
    <qwer>
    <zxcv c="c" b="b"/>
    <vcxz c="c" b="b"/>
    </qwer>
    <baz e="e" d="d"/>
    <bar>
    <fdsa g="g" f="f"/>
    <asdf g="g" f="f"/>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

**Desired Output XML:**

```
<foo a="a" b="b" c="c">
    <bar>
        <asdf f="f" g="g"/>
        <fdsa f="f" g="g"/>
    </bar>
    <baz d="d" e="e"/>
    <qwer>
        <vcxz b="b" c="c"/>
        <zxcv b="b" c="c"/>
    </qwer>
</foo>
```

How can I make the transform apply to **all** elements so all of an element's children will be in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to make the transform apply to all elements, you need a template to match all elements, as opposed to having a template that just matches the specific "foo" element

```
<xsl:template match="*">
```

Note that, you would have to change the current template that matches "node()" to exclude elements:

```
 <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]|@*">
```

Within this template, you will also need code to select the attributes, because your "foo" template at the moment will ignore them (`<xsl:apply-templates />` does not select attributes).

Actually, looking at your requirements, items 1 to 3 can all be done with a single XSLT. For example, to remove comments, you could just ignore it from the template that currently matches node()

```
<xsl:template match="node()[not(self::comment())][not(self::*)]|@*">
```

Try the following XSLT, will should achieve points 1 to 3

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::comment())][not(self::*)]|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: The template `<xsl:template match="node()[not(self::comment())][not(self::*)]|@*">` can actually be replaced with just `<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()|@*">` which may increase readability. This is because "node()" matches elements, text nodes, comments and processing instructions. In your XSLT, elements are picked up by the other template, text nodes by the built-in template, and comments you want to ignore, leaving just processing instructions.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks very similar to the XSLT posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4091243/288341).  I would like to do everything with the transform as you suggested, but I'm still having trouble getting rid of the comments.

Comment: I have spotted my mistake. "node()" also matches comments, so my XSLT was infact in error it has two templates matching comments with the same priority. I've amended it to correctly ignore comments now.

Comment: Actually, "node()" also matches elements too, so I have made a correction for that also!

Comment: I've added a final paragraph with some extra information you might find useful.

Comment: Yeah that is a lot cleaner. I'm still confused by your second comment though. I don't understand why your first iteration where you specified a template on `comment()` didn't just consume all comments since that template came before the template using `node()`.

Comment: In XSLT, it is considered an error to have two templates with the same priority matching the same node (comments are nodes). Some processors will use the first template, but this is not strictly correct behaviour. Now I mention it, another solution would be to have a template matching comment, and add a priority value to it; `<xsl:template match="comment()" priority="2" />`

Comment: Fantastic! I had two instances of the same class serialised by Xstream, with the elements in different orders. After using this I can now diff them in an editor. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

For fun, you can also do this programatically:

```
def x = '''<foo b="b" a="a" c="c">
    <qwer>
    <!-- A comment -->
    <zxcv c="c" b="b"/>
    <vcxz c="c" b="b"/>
    </qwer>
    <baz e="e" d="d"/>
    <bar>
    <fdsa g="g" f="f"/>
    <asdf g="g" f="f"/>
    </bar>
</foo>'''

def order( node ) {
    [ *:node.attributes() ].sort().with { attr ->
        node.attributes().clear()
        attr.each { node.attributes() << it }
    }
    node.children().sort { it.name() }
                   .each { order( it ) }
    node
}

def doc = new XmlParser().parseText( x )

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( order( doc ) )
```

If your nodes have content, then you need to change to:

```
def x = '''<foo b="b" a="a" c="c">
    <qwer>
    <!-- A comment -->
    <zxcv c="c" b="b">Some Text</zxcv>
    <vcxz c="c" b="b"/>
    </qwer>
    <baz e="e" d="d">Woo</baz>
    <bar>
    <fdsa g="g" f="f"/>
    <asdf g="g" f="f"/>
    </bar>
</foo>'''

def order( node ) {
    [ *:node.attributes() ].sort().with { attr ->
        node.attributes().clear()
        attr.each { node.attributes() << it }
    }
    node.children().sort()
                   .grep( Node )
                   .each { order( it ) }
    node
}

def doc = new XmlParser().parseText( x )

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( order( doc ) )
```

Which then gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo a="a" b="b" c="c">
  <baz d="d" e="e">Woo</baz>
  <bar>
    <fdsa f="f" g="g"/>
    <asdf f="f" g="g"/>
  </bar>
  <qwer>
    <zxcv b="b" c="c">Some Text</zxcv>
    <vcxz b="b" c="c"/>
  </qwer>
</foo>
```

Comment: I was going to see how well this performed against the transform method, but I'm getting an error: `Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.attributes() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

Comment: @ubiquibacon This works as expected. Try the same in Groovy Web Console.

Comment: @ubiquibacon Updated my answer for when nodes have contents (not in the original example)

Comment: @ubiquibacon if you have multiple string contents with nodes as children ie: `<node>Data<child>woo</child>More Data</node>` then things get a little funky with this method...  xslt and the accepted answer is probably the way to go (though it may be of interest to someone in the future to see the pure groovy route) :-)

Comment: Ah I see. My sample XML was not accurate :) Your fix works, but as you indicated XSLT is the way to go. The pure Groovy approach takes considerably longer... 18 seconds for a 14MB file as opposed to 5 second using the transform method.

Comment: Yeah, the xslt method is statically compiled optimised java all the way down