# Split xml onto separate lines using lxml

Tags: python, xml, whitespace, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to turn this:

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

into this:

```
<note>
<to>
Tove
</to>
<from>
Jani
</from>
<heading>
Reminder
</heading>
<body>
Don't forget me this weekend!
</body>
</note>
```

using the python library lxml. I'm very new to it and would also appreciate any resources to learn from.

Comment: what would the point of this be?

Comment: I'm using this output to diff large XML files that may not have consistent white space.

Comment: Then look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871076/are-there-any-free-xml-diff-merge-tools-available. you shouldn't be comparing xml using string operations.

Comment: This isn't my project. I'm just writing a script for my boss, and he wants them compared using diff for some reason. It seems simple enough but I can't figure out how to do it using lxml or elementTree.

Comment: Then tell your *boss* that trying to diff XML files this way is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to tackle this with lxml, I think it ends up being needlessly complicated.  The reason that it's complicated is that *it makes no sense*.  So, let's use tools that don't know XML from bupkus.

Assuming that you have your data in a file called `data.xml`, this might work:

```
sed '
  s/</\n</g
  s/>/>\n/g
' data.xml | sed '/^ *$/ d'
```

This assumes GNU sed.  The first `sed` command adds a newline before `<` or after `>`, and the second removes any blank lines.

I still think this is a terrible idea, but maybe this will work.  Given your sample input above, this produces:

```
<note>
<to>
Tove
</to>
<from>
Jani
</from>
<heading>
Reminder
</heading>
<body>
Don't forget me this weekend!
</body>
</note>
```

Comment: This does work, but I can't use regular expressions to edit the xml. I know, it doesn't seem to make sense, but I'm really not looking for a lecture. Just looking for a way to do it purely using an xml parser.