# Merging BizTalk binding files

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-deployment, btdf

I am using [BizTalk Deployment Framework](http://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/) (BTDF) for deploying my BizTalk solution. If I have made any changes to BizTalk bindings, I export them from BizTalk Administration Console and replace my PortBindingsMaster.xml bindings file (created by BTDF) with my exported bindings. I think many of you do the same. The problem is that when I do the export, BizTalk mixes up the order of XML nodes in bindings file, so when I am trying to merge with my source control, I'm getting over 9000 conflicts.

Is there any cool way to merge these BizTalk bindings?

Comment: +1, I'd love to see a good solution to this :)

Comment: In fact you are looking for XML comparison tool.

Comment: Various XML comparison tools mentioned in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871076/are-there-any-free-xml-diff-merge-tools-available

Comment: Visual Studio is good enough for that, but you still have to manage the conflicts. Even the tiniest change to a bindings mixes up the order the same level XML nodes and causes too many conflicts to manage.

Comment: @Arsen, VS compares XML files as text, but you are interested in something like this: http://www.altova.com/diffdog/xml-diff.html

Comment: DiffDog was one of the various XML comparison tools mentioned in the thread I linked.

Comment: It would be even cooler if that merge tool could take the tokenized PortBindingsMaster.xml, the SettingsFileGenerator.xml with the token values and a binding file exported from an environment and then allow you to compare and merge and update the PortBindingsMaster.xml with the tokenized settings.  Anyone want to start an Open Source Project to create one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating BTDF settings file generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211955/generating-btdf-settings-file-generator)

Answer (score 1):

Too much trouble trying to merge these. Get comfortable with the structure of a binding file and extract the parent node you need and copy it over to PortBindingsMaster.

The other problem with merging is if you use settingsfilegenerator, you'll need to merge that which can be potentially everywhere in PortBindingsMaster.

Answer (score 0):

There's a coolway by using NotePad++ Pretty XML plugin. Apply pretty xml to both Binding Files.