# After modifying an xml file and save it, changes &quot; to "

Tags: xml, vba, encode

I have to create a macro to change some tags in a given xml and save it again.
But after saving, all escaped characters are changed and also some carriage return are deleted.

Initial file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

...

```
<DataValidation xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <Range>R1C26</Range>
   <Type>List</Type>
   <CellRangeList/>
   <Value>&quot;Credit Limit&quot;</Value>
   <ErrorMessage>The header row should not be changed.</ErrorMessage>
   <ErrorTitle>Header Row</ErrorTitle>
</DataValidation>
```

After saving:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

...

```
<DataValidation xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
    <Range>R1C26</Range>
    <Type>List</Type>
    <CellRangeList/>
    <Value>"Credit Limit"</Value>
    <ErrorMessage>The header row should not be changed.</ErrorMessage>
    <ErrorTitle>Header Row</ErrorTitle>
</DataValidation>
```

My code is like this:

```
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xmlFile = outputFolder & "\" & f
xmlDoc.Load xmlFile
'Make changes here
xmlDoc.Save xmlFile
```

Can you help me to sort this out?

Comment: I need to send exactly the same xml, I just change some words that were translated.

Comment: There is no 'exact' XML.  Any valid XML consumer will accept the XML.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is any file comparator tool that allows me to skip CRLF? Because I need to compare original file and the modified one and this changes in the format make it difficult to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use XML Diff http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832512.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871076/are-there-any-free-xml-diff-merge-tools-available

Answer (score 0):

Finally I will provide users a tool to compare original and final xml files.
For instance, XML Notepad or Altova DiffDog, so they just can see the differences between files, but not the breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode during your 'Make changes script

Above for C# - Sorry.

For VBA, you could probably use something like:

```
Function UrlEncode(strString) 'As String
Dim strUrlEncode
Dim lngPos

For lngPos = 1 To Len(strString)
strUrlEncode = strUrlEncode & "%" & Right("0" & Hex(Asc(Mid(strString, lngPos, 1))), 2)
Next
UrlEncode = strUrlEncode

End Function
```

Ref: http://vbact.blogspot.com/2010/01/url-encode-in-vba.html