# Is there any way to compare two xml and it should ignore exact content text but it should compare content text by Data type

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

I have tried the below example and tried with different methods of `DiffBuilder` and `CompareMatcher` classes:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.xmlunit.diff.DefaultNodeMatcher;
import org.xmlunit.diff.ElementSelectors;
import org.xmlunit.matchers.CompareMatcher;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

public class XmlDemo4 {

    @Test
    public void demoMethod() {
    String actual = "<struct><int>3</int><boolean>false</boolean></struct>";
    String expected = "<struct><boolean>false</boolean><int>4</int></struct>";

    assertThat(actual, CompareMatcher.isSimilarTo(expected)
            .ignoreWhitespace().normalizeWhitespace().
            withNodeMatcher(new 
    DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byName,ElementSelectors.Default)));

    }

}
```

by running above code I am getting:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: Expected text value '4' but was '3' - comparing <int ...>4</int> at 
/struct[1]/int[1]/text()[1] to <int ...>3</int> at /struct[1]/int[1]/text()[1]:
<int>4</int>
     but: result was: 
<int>3</int>

at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)
at StringXml.XmlDemo4.demoMethod(XmlDemo4.java:29)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)

Process finished with exit code -1
```

here it is comparing content text also,
please suggest, is there any way to compare the content text with the data type and it should not compare with the exact content text

Answer (score 0):

You need some implementation of XML diff. I am not aware of Java, but there is some python library: https://pypi.org/project/xmldiff/

See also [Are there any free Xml Diff/Merge tools available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871076/are-there-any-free-xml-diff-merge-tools-available)

Answer (score 0):

`DifferenceEvaluator` is the class which decides whether a difference is `SIMILAR`, `EQUAL` or `DIFFERENT`. In my approach I am saying if there is any comparison of type `TEXT` then make the result of those comparison as `SIMILAR`
[Refer to XMLUnit 2.x](https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/DifferenceEvaluator)

```
import org.xmlunit.builder.DiffBuilder;
import org.xmlunit.diff.*;

import static org.xmlunit.diff.ComparisonType.TEXT_VALUE;

public class XmlDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String actual = "<struct><int>6</int><boolean>false</boolean></struct>";
    String expected = "<struct><boolean>false</boolean><int>4</int></struct>";

    Diff diff = DiffBuilder.compare(actual)
            .checkForSimilar()
            .withTest(expected)
            .ignoreWhitespace().normalizeWhitespace()
            .withNodeMatcher(new
                    DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byName))
            .withDifferenceEvaluator(DifferenceEvaluators.chain(DifferenceEvaluators.Default, DifferenceEvaluators.downgradeDifferencesToSimilar(TEXT_VALUE)))
            .build();

    for (Difference difference: diff.getDifferences())
        System.out.println(difference);
}
```

}